# Put two pork roasts in a crockpot overnight and forgot to plug it in

Tags: food-safety

I cooked a couple pork roasts earlier and took them out of the crock pot and then added two more in the still hot water/ juices etc.. Went to bed. Realized I must have unplugged the crockpot the night before when I got up in the morning to check them and take them out. Are these a definite throw aways?

Comment: there is a lot of questions like this. Try to widen your search a little and you should easily find an answer.

Comment: Yes, throw them out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the temperature. If any portion is between between 40 and 140 degrees F, then that's the danger zone, and you are indeed in danger if you consume them. Or, if part of it was colder and another part warmer, then the part in the middle is almost certainly again in the danger zone.

If everything was above 140 when you woke up, then you should be OK (but given the details I seriously doubt it).